# Python list append - can not change single items

Tags: python, list, append

I am trying to add a number of list to a list and later I want to modify the values.
Somehow all lists added at once seem to be linked.

```
data=[]

def data_extend(multiples):    
    a=["NV"]*2
    for i in range(multiples):
        data.append(a)
        
data_extend(2)
print(data)

data[0][1]=5
print(data)
```

the output is:

```
[['NV', 'NV'], ['NV', 'NV']]
[['NV', 5], ['NV', 5]]
```

I expected:

```
[['NV', 'NV'], ['NV', 'NV']]
[['NV', 5], ['NV', 'NV']]
```

Why is it like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you defined the `a` object before `for` loop, both of the items are the same object. If you only want one to change, you should do this:

```
data=[]

def data_extend(multiples):    
    for i in range(multiples):
        a=["NV"]*2
        data.append(a)
        
data_extend(2)
print(data)

data[0][1]=5
print(data)
```

Thus, all items of the list will be different items.